# Interdependent dropdowns Django JQuery Ajax - getting the url right

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have followed the following tutorial on how to get interdependent dropdowns functional with Django and JQuery / Ajax: http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/

I have the following inline-formset, when a product type is selected only the product within this type should be visible:

[image]

When selecting the ProductType the follwing Jquery is called:

```
$("select[name$='product_type']").change(function(){

    var url = "/order/" + $(this).val() + "/all_json_models";
    var product_type = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(products) {
        var options = '<option value="Z">Select a model</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
           options += '<option value="' + products[i].pk + '">' + products[i].fields['description'] + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").html(options);
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").attr('disabled', false);
    });
})
```

I use following in my urls.py

```
(r'^order/(?P<product_type>[-\w]+)/all_json_models/$', 'all_json_models'),
```

my order.views.py

```
def all_json_models(request, product_type):
    current_product_type = ProductType.objects.get(pk=product_type)
    products = Product.objects.all().filter(product_type=current_product_type)
    json_models = serializers.serialize("json", products)
    return HttpResponse(json_models, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Now i when i change the product type dropdown i receive the follwowing error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/6/all_json_models/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

When i click on the link:

```
TypeError at /order/5/all_json_models/
'str' object is not callable
```

As this is the first time i am using url referencing with Ajax i am lost in what the correct syntax should be. Any idea's?

Comment: Can you use firebug and print the request sent by the Ajax call ?

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/3/all_json_models
 
301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
  6ms 
jquery.min.js (regel 16)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/3/all_json_models/
 
500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
  22ms

Comment: i think it has someting to do with this line: var url = "/order/" + $(this).val() + "/all_json_models"; i do not know what i should place in the "/order/" part. /order/ is nothing in my application.

Comment: This `var url = "/order/" + $(this).val() + "/all_json_models"` will give you the dynamic URL based on the selected option in the HTML select input, `$(this)` is the selected HTML input select, and `.val()` is the jQuery API that will give you the value. so I still need what is being sent to the server, the hole request with the parameters !

Comment: i am not sure what to send, could you give an example?

Comment: In firebug, Net tab, then in the Ajax request (after you do the select change), Params tab, copy what is in it and print it here !

Comment: Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.7,nl;q=0.3
Connection keep-alive
Cookie csrftoken=kVA78XlelB2PDxyTc1iPnijyHxvVcyOw
Host 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer http://127.0.0.1:8000/orderline_formset/1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: That is the Headers tab, the tab before the Headers, can show you the sent parameters :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63589/discussion-between-e-nouri-and-phicon).

Answer (score 1):

In your views `def all_json_models(request, product_type):` the URL controller `^order/(?P<brand>[-\w]+)/all_json_models/$` call the view with the parameter `brand` not `product_type` !

For more protection you can modify the `^order/(?P<brand>[-\w]+)/all_json_models/$` to only capture an ID, since you send the product_type id and not the product_type itself, `^order/(?P<brand>[-\d]+)/all_json_models/$`. What you can do is send the product_type itself, it helps for the SEO ;) !

You need to be more careful about your code, and the way you treat and capture exceptions !

Also: The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json. The default encoding is UTF-8. (Source: RFC 4627).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I changed the question code. Still have the same error.

Comment: You need to give more information about the error, when it happen, line number ? try to debug a bit yourself, it is a very good habit that will help you resolve the future bugs you will have and believe me, you will have a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py you are using the tutorial syntax, but using your own in the view.

Try:

```
(r'^order/(?P<product_type>[-\w]+)/all_json_models/$', 'all_json_models'),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I changed the question code. Still have the same error.